# iTunes Connect requires iPhone 5 screenshots for non-iPhone5 app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app doesn't support 4-inch retina display (no iPhone 5 splash screen or Default-586h@2x.png in project), but ITC still requires screenshots for it. Is it mandatory even for non-iPhone 5 apps? Should I just use screenshots of my app in letterbox mode or is there a way to specify directly that my app doesn't support iPhone 5?

Comment: Are you sure that it's required? Where exactly do you get a failure message?

Comment: Yes, in ITC at app's page there's "Missing screenshots(1)" in status field.

Comment: What does the Apple Docu sais, about reqired screenshots?

Answer (score 4):

You could just fire up the simulator in 4inch mode and get the right sized screen shots there